# Change project in sublime text, sourcetree & codekit

Tags: automation, sublime-text-2, web-development

I'm a web developer, and often need to switch between projects. This means I need to:

- Change project in Sublime Text 2
- Change project in CodeKit
- Change project in SourceTree

Note: I'm using Mac OSX 10.9.1

Considering these are all changing to the same project folder, I wonder if there's a way of automating this task so I change all of them at the same time. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: seeing as these are 3 completely unrelated programs, I doubt it...

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text and SourceTree both have command line tools (`subl` and `stree` respectively), so you could write a simple script to call both of those with the current directory as an argument.

If you keep your .sublime-project files in your project directories, you could call `subl` with that instead.

Unfortunately, neither Sublime Text nor SourceTree offer AppleScript automation.

Haven't got a clue about CodeKit, as I don't use it.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I meant. However, I don't really know how to wire a script like this.